# concise definition of variable Multi-exponential function(s) within a loop (or in a class)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, numpy

i'm trying to define a callable sum-of-exponentials function with a variable number of terms, in a condensed code. the concept i'm looking for should be applicable to any sort mathematical function with repetitive terms.

the individual functions should look like this:

```
from numpy import exp, zeros

def ExpDec1(x,y0,t0,A,a1,tau):
    y = zeros(len(x))
    for k,l in enumerate(x):
        if l >= t0:
            y[k] = (A/a1)*(a1*exp(-l/tau)
    return y

def ExpDec2(x,y0,t0,A,a1,a2,tau1,tau2):
    y = zeros(len(x))
    for k,l in enumerate(x):
        if l >= t0:
            y[k] = (A/(a1+a2))*(a1*exp(-l/tau1) + a2*exp(-l/tau2))
    return y
...
```

some searching directed me to use classes, but i'm not very familiar with classes. my class attempt looks like this:

```
class ExpDec(object):
    from numpy import exp, zeros
    def __init__(self,n,x,y0,t0,A,a,tau):
        self.n = n
        self.x = x
        self.y0 = y0
        self.t0 = t0
        self.A = A
        self.a = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]
        self.tau = [tau1,tau2,tau3,tau4,tau5]
    def ExpDec(self):#n,x,y0,t0,A,a,tau):
        y = zeros(len(x))
        norm_fac = a[0]
        exponant = exp(-l/tau[0])
        for i in range(n-1):
            norm_fac += a[i+1]
            exponant += exp(-l/tau[i+1])
        for k,l in enumerate(x):
            if l >= t0:
                y[k] = y0 + ((A/norm_fact)*exponant)
        return y
```

and i was calling it with:

```
x = np.linspace(-10,100,1101)
y = ExpDec.ExpDec(n=1,x=x,y0=0,t0=0,A=1,a=1,tau=15)
print(y)
```

with an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-5f7bab6f83a6> in <module>()
      1 x = np.linspace(-10,100,1101)
      2 #y = ExpDec.ExpDec()
----> 2 y = ExpDec.ExpDec(n=1,x=x,y0=0,t0=0,A=1,a=1,tau=15)
      3 
      4 print(y)

TypeError: ExpDec() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'
```

any help would be appreciated!
thank you.